# sort each column of correlation independently and get index values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to know the ordering from highest correlation to lowest correlation for each column in my `DataFrame` relative to every other column.

#### Example

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6, 4).round(2), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

Looks like:

```
      A     B     C     D
0  0.44  0.41  0.46  0.47
1  0.46  0.02  0.85  0.82
2  0.78  0.76  0.93  0.83
3  0.88  0.93  0.72  0.12
4  0.15  0.20  0.44  0.10
5  0.28  0.61  0.09  0.84
```

The correlation table looks like:

```
print df.corr()

          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000  0.702557  0.689214  0.005000
B  0.702557  1.000000  0.038306 -0.113245
C  0.689214  0.038306  1.000000  0.074773
D  0.005000 -0.113245  0.074773  1.000000
```

I want column `B` to be ordered `['B', 'A', 'C', 'D']`.  A `DataFrame` should look like this?

```
   A  B  C  D
A  A  B  C  D
B  B  A  A  C
C  C  C  D  A
D  D  D  B  B
```

Also, I plan on doing this on an `DataFrames` from 20-40 thousand columns wide, so performance is an issue.

Comment: How about getting the indices as numeric values rather than strings, would that work for you? And as a NumPy array as output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
In [11]:
df.corr().apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).index)

Out[11]:
   A  B  C  D
A  A  B  C  D
B  B  A  A  C
C  C  C  D  A
D  D  D  B  B
```

So this applies `sort_values` on each column and returns the index

Not sure how this will scale on a 40k column df but the problem is that currently `sort_values` on a df can only sort by a specific column or a row df-wide

Answer (score 0):

So you need a function that calculates the co-varience and standard deviation.

```
def std(l):
    m = sum(l)/float(len(l))
    return((sum([(m-k)*2 for k in l])/float(len(m)))**0.5)

import itertools as itt

def pc(l1,l2):
    m1 = sum(l1)/float(len(l1))
    m2 = sum(l2)/float(len(l2))
    cov = sum([(k[1]-m2)*(k[0]-m1)for k in itt.zip(l1,l2)])/flaot(len(itt.zip(l1,l2)))
    return(cov / (std(l1)*std(l2)))
```

now that you have the functions you need you just iterate through all the pairs of rows and get the data you need and do what ever it is you need to do with it.